# ManyToManyField value in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

So when I am routing to api/ to view my models I am not seeing what I expected to see.
I wanted to see the names of the strats that I grouped in Strat_Basket model in the variable basket but instead I see their ids which is generated by DJANGO automatically.
I want to see the names rather than numbers in the strat_basket view. It is more informative that's why.

models.py

```
class Strats(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
class Strats_Basket(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    basket = models.ManyToManyField(Strats, blank=True, related_name='list')
```

serializers.py:

```
class StratsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Strats
        fields = ('id', 'name')
class Strats_BasketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Strats_Basket
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'basket')
```

views.py:

```
class StratsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StratsSerializer
    queryset = Strats.objects.all()
class Strats_BasketView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = Strats_BasketSerializer
    queryset = Strats_Basket.objects.all()
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'strats', views.StratsView, 'strats')
router.register(r'strats_basket', views.Strats_BasketView, 'strats_basket')
```

API OUTPUT:

strats:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "strat1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "strat2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "strat3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "strat4"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "strat5"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "strat6"
    }
]
```

strats_basket:
Instead of 1,2,4 I want to see strat1, strat2, strat4.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Basket 1",
        "basket": [
            1,
            2,
            4
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Basket 2",
        "basket": [
            3,
            5,
            6
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SerializerMethodField and inside the method return `names` list using `values_list` with `flat=True`

```
class Strats_BasketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     
    basket = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     
    def get_basket(self, obj):
        return obj.basket.all().values_list('name', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Strats_Basket
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'basket')
```

Comment: it is now displaying the names correctly but another problem is raised. Now I am not getting the list option of the strats model. The basket field is changed due to `basket = serializers.SerializerMethodField()` and I want that to create new objects.

Comment: @I'mTreaSUre you can change the field name for  `SerializerMethodField`  to some another name like `basket_list` and then include this field inside the `Meta.fields`